# Boost Geometry: Calculate vector difference

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-geometry

How can I calculate the difference of two points? For example: `(5,7) - (2,3) = (3,4)`

```
using point = boost::geometry::model::point<int, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>
point p1 (2, 3);
point p2 (5, 7);
point dif;
vector_difference(p2, p1, dif);
// dif equals (3,4)
```

Is there an existing function that I overlooked?
[`boost::geometry::difference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/difference.html) does not calculate vector-difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do :

```
dif = p2 - p1;
```

From : [Boost - uBLAS documentation - Vector Substraction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.htm)

EDIT : Or - with points, no vectors:

```
template<typename Point1, typename Point2>
void subtract_point(Point1 & p1, Point2 const & p2)
```

From : [Boost - Point Subsctraction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/arithmetic/subtract_point.html)

Comment: `subtract_point` does the job. Thanks, I should have found that :D